# Google DataFlow: Read from BigQuery, combine three string fields, write key/value fields to Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

None of the provided DataFlow templates match what I need to do, so I'm trying to write my own. I managed to run the example code like word count example without issue, so I tried to butcher together parts separate examples that read from BigQuery and writes to Spanner but there's just so many things in the source code I don't understand and cannot adapt to my own problem.

I'm REALLY lost on this and any help is greatly appreciated!

The goal is to use DataFlow and Apache Beam SDK to read from a BigQuery table with 3 string fields and 1 integer field, then concatenate the content of the 3 string fields into one string and put that new string in a new field called "key", then I want to write the key field and the integer field (which is unchanged) to a Spanner table that already exists, ideally append rows with a new key and update the integer field of rows with a key that already exists.

I'm trying to do this in Java because there is no i/o connector for Python. Any advice on doing this with Python are much appreciated.

For now I would be super happy if I could just read a table from BigQuery and write whatever I get from that table to a table in Spanner, but I can't even make that happen.

Problems:

- I'm using Maven and I don't know what dependencies I need to put in the pom file
- I don't know which package and import I need at the beginning of my java file
- I don't know if I should use readTableRows() or read(SerializableFunction) to read from BigQuery
- I have no idea how to access the string fields in the PCollection to concatenate them or how to make the new PCollection with only the key and integer field
- I somehow need to make the PCollection into a Mutation to write to Spanner
- I want to use an INSERT UPDATE query to write to the Spanner table, which doesn't seem to be an option in the Spanner i/o connector.

Honestly, I'm too embarrassed to even show that code I'm trying to run.

```
public class SimpleTransfer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create and set your PipelineOptions.
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

        // For Cloud execution, set the Cloud Platform project, staging location, and specify DataflowRunner.
        options.setProject("myproject");
        options.setStagingLocation("gs://mybucket");
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);

        // Create the Pipeline with the specified options.
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        String tableSpec = "database.mytable";

        // read whole table from bigquery
        rowsFromBigQuery =
            p.apply(
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                    .from(tableSpec);

        // Hopefully some day add a transform

        // Somehow make a Mutation
        PCollection<Mutation> mutation = rowsFromBigQuery;

        // Only way I found to write to Spanner, not even sure if that works.
        SpannerWriteResult result = mutation.apply(
            SpannerIO.write().withInstanceId("myinstance").withDatabaseId("mydatabase").grouped());

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of questions. I will do my best to answer the main one: How do you code a pipeline to do this - , but you'll need to create separate questions for other tihngs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's intimidating to deal with these strange data types, but once you get used to the `TableRow` and `Mutation` types, you'll be able to code robust pipelines.

The first thing you need to do is take your `PCollection` of `TableRow`s, and convert those into an intermediate format that is convenient for you. Let's use Beam's `KV`, which defines a key-value pair. In the following snippet, we're extracting the values from the `TableRow`, and concatenating the string you want:

```
rowsFromBigQuery
            .apply(
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings()
                                                     TypeDescriptors.integers()))
                    .via(tableRow -> KV.of(
                               (String) tableRow.get("myKey1")
                               + (String) tableRow.get("myKey2")
                               + (String) tableRow.get("myKey3"),
                               (Integer) tableRow.get("myIntegerField"))))
```

Finally, to write to Spanner, we use `Mutation`-type objects, which define the kind of mutation that we want to apply to a row in Spanner. We'll do it with another `MapElements` transform, which takes N inputs, and returns N outputs. We define the *insert or update* mutations there:

```
myKvPairsPCollection
            .apply(
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(Mutation.class))
                    .via(elm -> Mutation.newInsertOrUpdateBuilder("myTableName)
                                    .set("key").to(elm.getKey())
                                    .set("value").to(elm.getValue()));
```

And then you can pass the output to that to `SpannerIO.write`. The whole pipeline looks something like this:

```
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        String tableSpec = "database.mytable";

        // read whole table from bigquery
        PCollection<TableRow> rowsFromBigQuery =
            p.apply(
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(tableSpec));

        // Take in a TableRow, and convert it into a key-value pair
        PCollection<Mutation> mutations = rowsFromBigQuery
            // First we make the TableRows into the appropriate key-value
            // pair of string key and integer.
            .apply(
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings()
                                                     TypeDescriptors.integers()))
                    .via(tableRow -> KV.of(
                               (String) tableRow.get("myKey1")
                               + (String) tableRow.get("myKey2")
                               + (String) tableRow.get("myKey3"),
                               (Integer) tableRow.get("myIntegerField"))))
            // Now we construct the mutations
            .apply(
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(Mutation.class))
                    .via(elm -> Mutation.newInsertOrUpdateBuilder("myTableName)
                                    .set("key").to(elm.getKey())
                                    .set("value").to(elm.getValue()));

        // Now we pass the mutations to spanner
        SpannerWriteResult result = mutations.apply(
            SpannerIO.write()
                    .withInstanceId("myinstance")
                    .withDatabaseId("mydatabase").grouped());

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();

    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! Do you know what I need to import and/or which dependencies I need in the pom file?